# How to send clickable link and Mail in Chatterbot flask app

Tags: python, flask, bots, chatterbot

I am using chatterbot, I want to send clickable link and Mail as per message sent by the user. I cant find any link or reference on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using linkify.... pip install autolink... linkify (bot.get_response(usr_text))

Comment: It's better if you edit in order to format the code properly and explain what it does

Comment: Thanks , I was able to add link. Do you have any idea, how to send email alerts?